# Edge Coloring in graph

Tags: color, tikz-graphs

I'm looking for a simple solution to do Graph edge coloring, even following the `tkz-graph` documentation, seems my graph edges aren't being colored (neither line width is being changed), probably I'm doing something wrong that I couldn't notice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
    \Vertex[L=$v$]{v}
    \EA[unit=3,L=$u_2$](v){u2}
    \NO[L=$u_1$](u2){u1}
    \NO[L=$u_0$](u1){u0}    
    % How to draw a \vdots between $u_2$ and $u_n$?
    \SO[L=$u_n$,unit=3](u2){un}
    \Edge[lw=0pt,color=red,label=0](v)(u0)
    \Edge[lw=1pt,color=green,label=1](v)(u1)
    \Edge[lw=2pt,color=blue,label=2](v)(u2)
    \Edge[lw=15pt,color=orange,label=n](v)(un)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that adding `\SetUpEdge` the code above works, as we can seee in MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetUpEdge
    \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
    \Vertex[L=$v$]{v}
    \EA[unit=3,L=$u_2$](v){u2}
    \NO[L=$u_1$](u2){u1}
    \NO[L=$u_0$](u1){u0}    
    % How to draw a \vdots between $u_2$ and $u_n$?
    \SO[L=$u_n$,unit=3](u2){un}
    \Edge[lw=0pt,color=red,label=0](v)(u0)
    \Edge[lw=1pt,color=green,label=1](v)(u1)
    \Edge[lw=2pt,color=blue,label=2](v)(u2)
    \Edge[lw=15pt,color=orange,label=n](v)(un)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: Unfortunately, Mr. Marmot removed his answer.